# Using msal.js to call web api but failed in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I follow the document to get accesstoken and then call the web api protected by azuread.I'm using msal.js libary.
Firstly I'm using a button to login in,here is my code
const myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

```
function signIn() {
    myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest)
        .then(loginResponse => {
            alert('id_token acquired at: ' + new Date().toString());
            console.log('id_token acquired at: ' + new Date().toString());
            console.log(loginResponse);

            if (myMSALObj.getAccount()) {
                alert("already get account");
                showWelcomeMessage(myMSALObj.getAccount());
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(loginRequest);
            console.log("loginPopUp:" + error);
        });
}
```

everything works fine both in a html file and aspx file
and then after login confirmed
I'm using another button to call a api,code as belows.

```
function seeProfile() {
    alert('call profile');
    alert(myMSALObj.getAccount().toString());
    if (myMSALObj.getAccount()) {
        alert();
        myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(loginRequest).then(
            response => {
                alert(response);
                //callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphMailEndpoint, response.accessToken, updateUI);
                // success response
            }).catch(function (error) {
                alert(error);
                console.log(error);
            });
}
}
```

just to get token from `acquireTokenSilent`，it works well in my html file.
But failed in a .aspx webform. No feedback in the function,not in the then() and catch function

Comment: If I put the body to   <form id="form1" runat="server">,cacheitem will be failed,put the wrong key.

Comment: Post a issue too https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1541

Comment: In the login request parameter, are you mentioning the scope correctly. Could you please share more information on callMSGraph function. Also, set debug points in the browser developer tools to check the flow